# webmatrix compiles when jquery .slideToggle duration is fast, but not slow

Tags: jquery, webmatrix

I've using this code in a `cshtml` file in `WebMatrix 3`, when having the `slideToggle`duration at fast it compiles, but when setting the duration to slow it gives me an error and wont compile. Why is this, is it a setup malfunction from me or is it a malfunction in `WebMatrix 3`?

Don't think it matters, but I test in `IE9`

The code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var menu = "#divA";
            var btn = "#btnB";

            $(menu).hide();
            $(btn).click(function ()
            {
                $(menu).slideToggle('fast', function() // if this changes to 'slow' it won't compile //
                {

                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <table id="divA">
        // content
    </table>
    <a href="#" id="btnB">btn</a>
```

This is the compilation error. Tried translating it from danish, rather than having a picture.

```
Server error in program '/'.

compile error 
Description: An error occurred while processing a resource, that is necessary for this request.
Read the following details about the error, and make changes in the source code if necessary. 

Error message about compile function: The compile function failed with the error code -1073741819.

Show detailed output from compile function:
C:\Users\MichaelTot\Desktop>
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.Data\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.Data.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
"C:\Users\MichaelTot\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e2d3f28\b668b7d8\assembly\dl3\6739f732\0072c6b9_eb47ce01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WebMatrix.WebData\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WebMatrix.WebData.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\NuGet.Core\v4.0_1.6.30117.9648__31bf3856ad364e35\NuGet.Core.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Razor.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Administration\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
"C:\Users\MichaelTot\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e2d3f28\b668b7d8\App_Code.n6jmjasw.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
/out:"C:\Users\MichaelTot\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e2d3f28\b668b7d8\App_Web_layout.cshtml.65a2d1ee.cfadhwvw.dll"
/D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-
"C:\Users\MichaelTot\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e2d3f28\b668b7d8\App_Web_layout.cshtml.65a2d1ee.cfadhwvw.0.cs"
"C:\Users\MichaelTot\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e2d3f28\b668b7d8\App_Web_layout.cshtml.65a2d1ee.cfadhwvw.1.cs"

Version info: Microsoft .NET Framework version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET version:4.0.30319.18045
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is working as well?  Will help for comparison.

Comment: @asymptoticFault updated the code for clearence

Comment: So once you change the value within the single quotes to *slow* it gives you an compiler error?  What is the error?

Comment: @asymptoticFault added the compilation error message, that shows when changing quote to `slow`

Comment: Try double quotes around it instead of single: "slow"